# How do I replace the side mirror glass in a 2004 WRX?

Tags: subaru, wrx, wing-mirrors

My aged but well-loved 2004 Subaru WRX wagon has been passed on to my youngest as the going to college car. Unfortunately, 2020: the car has sat largely idle for more than a year now. During that time, somehow both the driver and passenger side mirrors decided to crack. There’s no indication of impact and the mirror controls still work fine.

So, the question is: how do I replace the mirror glass in those housings so the reflection is a little less surreal?

Comment: Does the WRX have heated or non-heated mirrors?

Comment: These are basic remote controlled mirrors. No heating, not special features! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mirror glass is fixed by adhesive pads, which usually come with the replacement glass. Use a heat gun on the old mirror glass to soften the glue, and gently pull it out. Wear gloves, in case of shards.

Clean off any remaining old glue pad with alcohol, then put the new pads on the glass, and gently push into place.

Comment: [This gives visual reference and credence to what is said here.](https://youtu.be/hx7RDQnamjA)